# Having Issue on Conditional Binding With Vue Form Input Bindings

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Can someone please help me to figure it our how to add a condition to this Binding in a way that output different binding based on if the input has none, one or many Comma in it?

```
<p>{{ target}}</p>
<input v-model="target" placeholder="Enter Your Target" />
```

so in case that input has no comma the output will be

```
You Entered `London`
```

If One Comma

```
You Entered `London` AND `Paris`
```

and if many

```
You Entered `London` AND `Paris` AND `Rome`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like following:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      target: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      return this.target && '`' + this.target.replaceAll(",", "` AND `") + '`'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>You Entered {{ result }}</p>
  <input v-model="target" placeholder="Enter Your Target" />
</div>
```